# Plotting vectors in a vectorplot along edges of a plot

Tags: plotting

I am plotting a vector plot that should represent trajectories through a space of values.

When the trajectories hit one of the boundaries (the values 0 or 1 on each axis), the trajectories are not supposed to be able to go any further. So at that point, the trajectories should evolve along the edge.

I am wondering how to produce this in a plot.

Currently, the vector plot doesn't 'know' that the trajectories cannot go above 1 or below 0 on each axis, so they aren't producing the trajectories I need along the edge. I'd be grateful to anyone who knows how to solve this.

```
x = 2;
y = 1;
k = 3;


Plota = VectorPlot[{
   
   (1/2 (x k - 
       2 y - (x - y) (-1 + 
          k) mbar + ((x^2) k - (x*y) (-1 + k) x) x) (-1 + x)),
   
   (1/2 (-1 + k) (y + x (-1 + vbar) - x vbar + 
       y (x (-1 + vbar) - y vbar)))
   
   },
  
  {vbar, 0, 1}, {mbar, 0, 1},
  
  VectorStyle -> {"Arrow", Black, Opacity[1]},
  VectorScale -> {0.01, 6, None},
  VectorPoints -> 13,
  
  StreamPoints -> 200,
  StreamScale -> {Full, All, 0.05},
  StreamStyle -> {"Line", Black, Opacity[0.5]},
  
  FrameLabel -> {"v", "m"},
LabelStyle -> Directive[ 25, Black, FontFamily -> "Calibri Light"]]
```

That produces this:

[image]

Comment: So the expected outcome is an additional arrow that moves anti-clockwise along the frame?

Comment: In this particular case, it would be going horizontally right when m = 0, and vertically down for v = 1. When v = 1, v isn't supposed to be growing any further (since there is no value above 1), but m is still falling. I guess I could just manually plot that, but was wondering if there is a neater way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to use `VectorPlot` for this purpose:

```
x = 2;
y = 1;
k = 3;

v[vbar_, mbar_] := {
  (1/2 (x k - 2 y - (x - y) (-1 + k) mbar + ((x^2) k - (x*y) (-1 + k) x) x) (-1 + x)),
  (1/2 (-1 + k) (y + x (-1 + vbar) - x vbar + y (x (-1 + vbar) - y vbar)))
  }
vRestricted[vbar_, mbar_] := Which[
  vbar > 0.98 || vbar < 0.02, Projection[v[vbar, mbar], {0, 1}],
  mbar > 0.98 || mbar < 0.02, Projection[v[vbar, mbar], {1, 0}],
  True, v[vbar, mbar]
  ]

VectorPlot[
  vRestricted[vbar, mbar],
  {vbar, 0, 1},
  {mbar, 0, 1},
  FrameLabel -> {"v", "m"},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[25, Black, FontFamily -> "Calibri Light"]
  ]
```

[image: Output]

A caveat is that this is very sensitive to the arguments that you supply to `VectorPlot`. If you sample the space differently, you may miss the vertical and horizontal arrows, get multiple rows of them, or get arrows on the border that aren't perfectly aligned.

A more reliable way of doing this would be to draw the arrows along the border manually, for example using the `Epilog` option.

One way to take this idea further if you want to have a smooth transition from the outer behavior and the inner behavior, would be to linearly interpolate `v` and the projection depending on how close to the border the position is.

Comment: Thank you! This is very clear.